# transfer data from a class to webpage in flask

Tags: python, class, session, flask

I packed some defs in a class to do a work of translation text into the other language using Bing or Google translation API. and using a Flask to render templates as you may aware of.

However, when do the translation, I have some status and progress information, like completed 10% and etc during translate the paragraphs. but that information generated in the translation class as you may imagine - the class does the translation job.

However, in my Flask app, after call the class do the translation I want to have an ajax call from the webpage to the Flask App to retrieve that 10% information which generated from that class.

Here is what I did:

1. If I don't use any class, put all the defs within the main Flask App file, I can use the a global variable store the 10% information, but that makes the codes complex and I want to pack all the associated defs in a class.
2. in the Flask App, I was trying to use session['translation_pos'] to retrieve the information that I stored in session['translation_pos'] in the class, but it seems not works.

I use python 3 and Flask, I don't know how to get this progress percentage information from the class - where the data generated - to the App.

May be one of the way would like store the number in a text file or some places, and read the file in the App, but I was thinking that certainly shouldn't the way to handle this problems.

Would anyone could advise with some idea that will be much appreciated.

Thank you All.

Comment: did you try to use flash ? here is a link if you haven't tried it. [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a different approach to running the task, using something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [Redis Queue](http://python-rq.org/) - covered very well [here in the mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs).

By using one of these, you can run the task and query the runner periodically for progress to report it back to the user.

If it were me, for the data processing I would store this in a database. When the task is completed, it gets re-queried and passed through to the UI as a template variable (or streamed from an ajax function if it's a large data set).